# Need a SQL query to fetch data from 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

Now we need a SQL query to fetch the records where status in (failed,null) and retry count <10.obviously final result should contain id =1,2,3 but not 4

Comment: how are the tables related? and what should your output look like?

Comment: I have tried with union but it din worked..due to time contraint coundt provide the detail in proper format...exuse for that

Comment: Two questions. **Q1**. What should happen to the `id`'s, like `2` and `3`, that simply do not have an entry in `table_b`? You say one of the conditions is `retry_count < 10`, but this condition is not true if the `id` is not found in `table_b` in the first place. (`NULL` is not `< 10`). **Q2**. Is the matching between the tables by `id`, or by `id` AND `pin`?

Comment: @mathguy ..below answer worked for me..thank you for your effort

Comment: What, you can't be bothered to answer two simple questions? The reason I ask is that, very likely, others in the future who have a question similar to yours may very well find this thread in a Google search. It will help them to know EXACTLY what the problem was in the first place. But if that takes too much effort on your part - or if your time is too valuable to be spent on such minor things - that's your right; just don't expect others to spend theirs to help you though.

Comment: If the union query I provided you in your other question didn't work (what time constraint?), you should've said so in a comment on my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need a `join` and some attention to the `NULL` values:

```
select a.id
from tableA a left join
     tableB b
     on a.id = b.id
where (a.status is null or a.status = 'FAILED') and
      coalesce(b.retrycount, 0) < 10;
```

Comment: looks like some condition is missed.your query is giving thousands of records which doesnt satifsfy the condition

Comment: @javalearner - Gordon's query fits the filtering criteria you gave in your question. So if indeed "some condition is missed" the omission is *in your post*. You admit you don't have the time to write a decent question yet you still assume strangers will invest their time trying to help you. Poor show.

Comment: @APC..I have accpeted the answer ..it worked with some change...credit for Gordon ...I meant if something was missed in conjunction coalesce (which is quite new to me)with he could reply  ..rest of the stuff I can try it out..I made some changes to his query as per my requirement it worked...Next time will respond in proper format...thanks you for your feedback :-)

Comment: @gordon linoff..thanks alot for your effort